# Does the flow plugin work with remote debugging in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

- Does the flow plugin work with remote debugging in Intellij?
- I am using flow plugin in Intellij.
- I see that it is not getting enabled, when I have a remote debug configuration.
- [image: flow plugin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From the documentation of the plugin ( thanks to my colleague ), it says that, remote connections is not supported.

[image]